# How to display multiples images equally in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a photo gallery app and came across some obstacles. I want to have each image take equal portion of the div, for example if there are two images, each image takes up 50% of the div, and if there are three images, each images takes up 33.33% of the div, etc. Further, is there a way to format those images to be in square dimensions through css?

Also, I have the photos-gallery div that contains h2 and photos-gallery-content div. Currently, I am hardcoding the height for the photos-gallery-content div to fit inside the parent div, but is there a way to make that div take the remainder of the height of its parent div?

Eventually I want the pictures to render dynamically using React so any recommendations/advice on that would help a lot too.

Here is my code:

```css
#photos {
  width: 634px;
  height: 339px;
}

.photos-gallery {
  width: 634px;
  height: 275.03px;
}

.photos-gallery-header {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.photos-gallery-content {
  height: 200px;
}

.photos-gallery-layout {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.photos-gallery-layout li {
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.photo {
  display: inline-flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.photo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="photos-gallery" class="photos content-block">
  <h2 class="photos-gallery-header"> 2 Photos </h2>
  <div class="photos-gallery-content">
    <ul class="photos-gallery-layout">
      <li class="photos-gallery-li">
        <div class="photo">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8pTwPlXb.jpg" />
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="photos-gallery-li">
        <div class="photo">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OPAR3PCb.jpg" />
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="photos-gallery-li">
        <div class="photo">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/A8eQsll.jpg" />
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used your HTML and wrote a little CSS to demonstrate how to:

1. Have any amount of items fit at equal widths in one row using flexbox (`display: flex` on the parent and `flex: 1` on the children)
2. Have `<img>` elements crop to the shape of the tallest element (in this case, a square) using `object-fit: cover` (note compatibility on [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit))

```css
.photos-gallery-layout {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.photos-gallery-li {
  flex: 1;
}

.photo,
.photo img {
  height: 100%;
}

.photo img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<ul class="photos-gallery-layout">
  <li class="photos-gallery-li">
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8pTwPlXb.jpg" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="photos-gallery-li">
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OPAR3PCb.jpg" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="photos-gallery-li">
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/A8eQsll.jpg" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```